# Mapped drives without letter in registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry, mapped-drive

I have a problem with finding all mapped drives on remote computer from my c# code. I can find drives in registry (HKEY_USERS\< USER >\Network). Each subkey named "$X" (where "$X" is letter) responds to mapped disk named "$X" for < USER >. But how can I find disks without letter. I can map them in cmd like this

```
net use <path>
```

Disk mapped like this is visible if I type

```
net use
```

but it's not visible in that registry.

How can I solve it? I can't use "net use" command because I need to list mapped drives for all users under specific computer.

Comment: Such a mapping isn't persistent, is it?  Why would it be stored in the registry?

Comment: You're right, it disappears after restart, I didn't know that, in that case I don't need to read it, but just out of curiosity, where is it stored? How net use know that there's such mapping

Comment: Somewhere in memory.  (In the kernel, probably.)